# Embedding php 'if' statements in HTML not executing correctly in PHP7

Tags: php, html, php-7, ubuntu-16.04

I have a PHP MVC website, with a lot of code like this in my views:

```
<? if($this->unallocatedCount > 0 && Session::get("user_internal") == "1"): ?>
    something
<? endif; ?>
```

It works perfectly fine in PHP5, however I am hosting a copy of the same website on a Linux server with PHP7 and this code isn't executed correctly. What it does is execute this: `<? if($this->` and just plainly output the rest of it.

Is it typical PHP7 behaviour or do I just need to make changes to my PHP settings on the server?

Comment: php short_open_tags is disabled by default in php 7 , you may have to enable it from php.ini , take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: php 7:- short_open_tag are disabled.

Comment: So is `short_open_tag` the correct spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Php 7, short tags are disabled by default. You have to fix it

```
<?php if($this->unallocatedCount > 0 && Session::get("user_internal") == "1"): ?>
    something
<?php endif; ?>
```

or enable short tags in your php.ini.

> short_open_tag=On

then restart the server...

Answer (score 0):

You should replace [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

```
<?php if($this->unallocatedCount > 0 && Session::get("user_internal") == "1"): ?>
    something
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why the Down Vote here?

Comment: Ehm.. what? I guess, I miss smth

Comment: There was a DV before which got to 0 now by my +1 ;)

Comment: Yeah, I've already seen it and did the same for @Anant cauze agree with his answer.

Comment: @bub  i am agreed with you and Dmytrechko   both.

Comment: All answers and the questions has been downvoted, some guys used to do it without a good reason and without leaving comments... maybe jealous guys. I often upvote when there is no good downvote reason.

Comment: There is also situation when guys downvote answers that they can't understand. For example, when you advice to use array_column + array_map instead of nested foreach-s. So it's pity, that there is no some mechanism to verify quality of answers.
Cause you forced to write simple solutions but it's not good for teaching others.